# Python thread.join(time) doesn't return back

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two functions defined as below:

function that makes a thread:

```
def join_group_thread(client, link):
    thread_queue = queue.Queue()
    thread_1 = threading.Thread(
        target=join_group,
        name="Join Group Thread",
        args=[client, link, thread_queue],
    )
    thread_1.start()
    thread_1.join(10)
    return thread_queue.get()
```

function that runs in the thread:

```
def join_group(client, params, queue):
    try:
        response = client.invoke(ImportChatInviteRequest(params))
    except Exception as e:
        response = str(e).replace("'","")
    queue.put(response)
```

In the `main()` I call `join_group_thread` like this:

```
result = join_group_thread(client, link)
```

As I have set time to 10 seconds here in `thread_1.join(10)` I expect `result = join_group_thread(client, link)` to take 10 seconds at most, but sometimes it hangs forever.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get):

> Queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an
>   item is available.

In other words, the timeout in `thread.join` is pointless because the Queue waits until the result is available. Use `thread_queue.get(block=False)` or `thread_queue.get_nowait()`.